# pandas - exponentially weighted moving average - similar to excel

Tags: python, pandas, mean

Consider I've a dataframe of 10 rows having two columns A and B as following :

```
    A  B
0  21  6
1  87  0
2  87  0
3  25  0
4  25  0
5  14  0
6  79  0
7  70  0
8  54  0
9  35  0
```

In excel I can calculate the `rolling` `mean` like this excluding the first row:
[image] [image]

How can I do this in pandas?

Here is what I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard() #copying the dataframe given above and calling read_clipboard will get the df populated
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'B'] = df[['A', 'B']].loc[i-1].mean()
```

This gives me the desired result matching excel. But is there a better pandas way to do it? I've tried using `expanding` and `rolling` did not produce desired result.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by what you are aiming for here. A 'standard' moving average of the series A with, for example, a window length of 2 would have the formula =AVERAGE(A2:A1) in cell B2, and not =AVERAGE(A1,B1) Given that you have already accepted an answer, I assume you've gotten exactly what you were after, but it would be cool if you find the time to provide some details.

Comment: I'm trying to create Heiken-Ashi candles. Current bar open value is average of open and close value of previous bar. For more details refer to this link https://www.quantiacs.com/Blog/Intro-to-Algorithmic-Trading-with-Heikin-Ashi.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an exponentially weighted moving average, rather than a simple moving average. That's why `pd.DataFrame.rolling` didn't work. You might be looking for [`pd.DataFrame.ewm`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html) instead.

Starting from

```
df

Out[399]: 
    A  B
0  21  6
1  87  0
2  87  0
3  25  0
4  25  0
5  14  0
6  79  0
7  70  0
8  54  0
9  35  0

df['B'] = df["A"].shift().fillna(df["B"]).ewm(com=1, adjust=False).mean()
df

Out[401]: 
    A          B
0  21   6.000000
1  87  13.500000
2  87  50.250000
3  25  68.625000
4  25  46.812500
5  14  35.906250
6  79  24.953125
7  70  51.976562
8  54  60.988281
9  35  57.494141
```

Even on just ten rows, doing it this way speeds up the code by about a factor of 10 with `%timeit` (959 microseconds from 10.3ms). On 100 rows, this becomes a factor of 100 (1.1ms vs 110ms).

Comment: You could use `adjust=False`, I think, something like `df["A"].shift().fillna(df["B"]).ewm(com=1, adjust=False).mean()`.

Comment: @DSM absolutely right. My eye kept skipping over that line. Updated.